# MS Access SQL, Rnd Function without numeric field

Tags: sql, ms-access, random, vba

Is it possible in a Microsoft Access query to use the Rnd() Function without specifying a numeric column (e.g. when my Primary Key contains Alpha characters) and still generate a different random number for each row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the 1st character;

```
rnd(asc(left([field],1)))
```

which should give a different result for each row, even if the char is the same

Comment: Cheers Alex, I've posted my own version of the answer but am going to accept yours because it uses the inbuilt functionality without the need of creating a custom function like I did : )

Answer (score 1):

It's simpler than I originally thought, this function can be used in exactly the same context as Rnd()

```
Public Function Rand(FieldName) As Single

    Rand = Rnd(1)

End Function
```

Then in SQL used as:

```
SELECT ID, Rand([ID]) FROM Table
```

By passing it a fieldname, we force the function to execute for each row in the query (eventhough we ignore the actual field in the function) and then evaluating the function to 1 will always return a different random number in the same way Rnd() would if executed in VB.